# Proof of quantum superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, superposition

My question is really very simple, how can one see that a spin 1/2 particle in a definite projection in z(say, up) is in a superposition of Sx states?

Comment: This is a tricky but beautiful question. From one point of view the equality can't be proven, it just expresses an experimental fact. From another you may prove it from more general symmetries about the theory. For the latter see for example chapter 3 of Holevo: *Probabilistic
and Statistical
Aspects of Quantum
Theory*. I think it is downloadable from Springer: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-88-7642-378-9

Comment: From what *assumptions* do you want to "prove" this?

Comment: Let me refrase: how can one see this without invoking amplitude interference..?

Comment: If I correctly understand what you're asking, one way to derive this is to assume that your system must have an $SO(3)$ rotational symmetry, and then ask what's the minimal Hilbert space supporting this group representation. That is, you're assuming: (1) the system is quantum (hence pure states must be represented by rays in a Hilbert space), (2) the system has $SO(3)$ symmetry.

Comment: ...Such a representation goes through the $SU(2)$ group, which uses the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) and acts on a 2D Hilbert space. From their eigenvector structure you derive the superposition formula for the three perpendicular spatial directions.

Comment: But how to see it from stern gerlach?

Comment: If you prepare your spin in the $+z$-direction by filtering through a $z$-oriented SG apparatus, and then you measure in the $x$-direction with the corresponding SG apparatus, you get + and - 50%/50% of the time. Same for the $y$-direction.

Comment: Check out Peres: [*Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-306-47120-5). He goes through this quite thoroughly, from the experimental results to the necessary Hilbert-space representation.

Comment: I know that if I prepare it in z+ I get x+ and x- but how can I see why? Is it because it is in a superposition or because it is half x+ and half x-?

Answer (score 2):

Classically we expect the x-component (and the y-component) of a unit vector to be zero when it is known that the z-component is $1$. But quantum mechanically we know that the outcome of $S_x$ measurement on any spin half state leads to either plus half or minus half. The correspondence principle says that the expectation value must mirror the classical counterpart.

Thus for a spin half polarised in the z-direction, we expect $$\langle S_x\rangle=\langle {\uparrow,z}|S_x|{\uparrow,z}\rangle=0$$
This means that in the x-basis, the $|{\uparrow,z}\rangle$ must be an equal superposition of up and down, ie:
$$|{\uparrow,z}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|{\uparrow,x}\rangle + \frac{e^{i\theta}}{\sqrt{2}}|{\downarrow,x}\rangle  $$

There is still a choice of phase but that doesn’t hinder the expectations. But whatever phase is chosen we should stick to that in expressing other states. And for simplicity we can choose $\theta=0$.

Comment: How do we know that it is not Just a mix of definite plus and minu states?

Comment: Because you can rotate your measuring device such that the outcome is always definite. In case of mixed state, that’s not possible. No matter how you rotate, all the outcomes will never be the same

Comment: Yes? I thought if you rotate it you get polatization mix in the New direction.

Comment: I mean if you rotate to x, then the above superposition state will always be up (or always down). But if it’s a mixture of up and down, you’ll get up or down depending on the state.

Comment: So yes, if you pass x+ through the x again, you get x+, as you should. That does not prove it was in a superposition before.

Comment: Say your states are all x+ but you’re measuring along z. Experimentally you have equal probability of measuring + or - that you can’t predict a priori. Now rotate your measuring device to measure along x, without changing the source. Now all your outcomes are +. Since you haven’t changed your input state but only the measurement, this should prove the superposition.

Comment: If the states are x+ and you measure them for x you will get +. I dont see how that proves that once they were in a definite z state you are also in a superposition of x...

Comment: Or rather how you can see it not prove it.

Comment: I would try and say that if you let z+ through x aparatus but do not measure, if you let it all through another z, you get z+ again. But, if you measure buy some plate or detector, like, you filtrate just x+, and then again let through z you get both z+ and z-, even if you let one electron at a time. So, if they are in definite x they give z+ and z- but if you just let them through, they give only z + which means they are not if definite x! But if they are not in definite x and still are getting through, what are they in? Obviously, in some indefinite x...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108983/discussion-between-zarko-tomicic-and-superfast-jellyfish).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a spin-1/2 particle in $\left|+\right>_{z}$ state, then we can write it in terms of the eigenstates of the $S_x$ operators as,
$$\left|+\right>_z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|+\right>_x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|-\right>_x.$$
Now whenever you try to measure the spin of the particle along x-axis, there is a 50% chance that it will be spin up and 50% chance that it will be spin down. The operator $S_z$ also obeys the following eigenvalue equation,
$$S_z \left|m\right>=m\hbar\left|m\right>,$$
where $\left|m\right>$ are the eigenstates of the $S_z$ operator.

You can try to see why this happens with the help of the eigenvalue of the $S^2$ operator. The $S^2$ operator is defined by,
$$S^2 = S_x^2 + S_y^2+S_z^2,$$
and it obeys the following eigenvalue equation,
$$S^2\left|m\right> = \frac{3}{4}\hbar^2\left|m\right>,$$
where $\left|m\right>$ is the eigenstate. Now the eigenvalue of $S^2$ is quite analogous to the square of the "magnitude" of some physical quantity in classical phyisics. *(e.g. In $L^2 = L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2$, $L^2$ is the square of the magnitude of total angular momentum)*. Now, as you can see the magnitude of the eigenvalue $\left(=\sqrt{3}\hbar/2\right)$ is greater than $\hbar/2$. This can be interpreted as that even though we have a particle with spin oriented along the z-axis, there is some amount of the total spin that is oriented along the directions perpendicular to it. This is the reasson why it can be written as a superposition of $S_x$ states. This is more of a physical expanation as to why this happens.

Mathematically speaking, this happens because the eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator of a quantum mechanical system forms a basis for the Hilbert space of the system. Hence any state of the system (which is a vector belonging to that Hilbert space), can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of that operator.

Comment: But your answer starts by assuming the very equality that the OP is asking to prove. It seems to me that that equation can't be proven, it just expresses an experimental fact.

Comment: @pglpm I haven't assumed anything, I have just restated it for clarity. The main explanation is rather through understanding the eigenvalue of ths $S^2$ operator.